# Rails subcategories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

How do I find and manage subcategories? (the find_subcategory method i'd defined does not seem to work.)

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_category, only: [:show]

def index
    @categories = Category.order(:name)
end

def show
end


private

def find_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id]) 
end

def find_subcategory
    @subcategory = Category.children.find(params[:parent_id])
end

end
```

I'm using the acts_as_tree gem, which has:

```
 root      = Category.create("name" => "root")
  child1    = root.children.create("name" => "child1")
  subchild1 = child1.children.create("name" => "subchild1")



root.parent   # => nil
  child1.parent # => root
  root.children # => [child1]
  root.children.first.children.first # => subchild1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you want your find_subcategory method to do, but if you want it to find all subcategories of the category with id in params[:id], then change it to

```
def find_subcategories
  @subcategories = Category.where(:parent_id => params[:parent_id]).all
end
```

In your original you're just looking for a single subcategory, and if you just want a single category you might as well just load it from it's id.

Comment: Yes great! That's exactly what I intended.

Comment: @Drenmi funnily enough i didn't put `.all` in my original answer, then i went back and added it as i thought it made it more obvious that we wanted a collection rather than a single record.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I suspected that was the case, as I was thinking along the same lines. Then I became a bit conflicted, because it might imply that without the `.all`, `.where` would just return one record.

Answer (score 2):

I know you accepted the answer, but [I've done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925068/how-do-you-create-a-model-with-categories-that-has-subcategories-using-rails) and so it might be beneficial to explain how we did it:

---

Firstly, we used the ancestry gem. <s>I think [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) is deprecated</s> -- `acts_as_tree` is better than `ancestry`, I forgot why we used it now - [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) works in a *very* similar way (`parent` column, `child` methods, etc).

I'll explain our implementation with `ancestry` - hopefully it will give you some ideas for `acts_as_tree`:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry #-> enables the ancestry gem (in your case it should be "acts_as_tree"
end
```

This will allow you to populate the `ancestry` (in your case `parent_id`) column in your `categories` model, and (most importantly) gives you the ability to [call the `child` methods](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree) attached to objects in the model:

```
@category.parent
@category.children
```

... etc.

--

The important thing to note here is *how* we're able to call the `child` objects (which would be *subcategories* in your case).

Your method is to create separate objects and have them inherit from each other. The beauty of `ancestry` / `acts_as_tree` is their added methods.

Any object with the correct `parent` ids can call their "children" as associative data:

[image]

In our case, we were able to associate all the objects using the `ancetry` column. This is slightly trickier than `acts_as_tree` because you have to provide the entire hierarchy in the column (which is lame), nonetheless the result is still the same:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @categories = Category.all
   end
end

#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<%= render @categories %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<%= category.name %>
<%= render category.children if category.has_children? %>
```

This will output the sub categories for you:

[image]

---

> How do I find and manage subcategories

You can do it like this:

```
@subcategories = Category.where parent_id: @category.id
```

*or* if you have your ancestry set up properly, you should be able to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/views/categories/show.html.erb
<% @category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
   <%= subcategory.name %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: That's super useful. Could you also post your Category model/structure?

Comment: https://github.com/richpeck/accountancy_demo/blob/master/app/models/category.rb I can post relevant code if you'd prefer